# Access Dictionary Object by String Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

I am trying to fill a Dictionary (JavaScript object) and retrieve values from it using a string index. For some reason, it always returns `undefined` when I try to retrieve the values.

My code goes something like this:

```
var _gauges = {};

//fill the gauges
_gauges[gaugeName] = gaugeObject;
```

And then I try to get access to it as follows:

```
    setValue: function (gaugeName, newValue) {
        var thisGauge = _gauges[gaugeName]; //always undefined
        console.log(_gauges); //output shows all the elements that were added to _gauges
        if (thisGauge) {
            thisGauge.setCell(0, 1, newValue);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Whats the value of gaugeName in both instances?

Comment: It is a simple string value... in this case it is "Gauge-0"

Comment: Are you sure that it is equal to `Gauge-0` in both instances?  Have you tried logging its value?

Comment: Ok that was a stupid typo! Thanks for pointing that out @RyanLynch

Comment: Go ahead and post an answer that explains what the solution to your issue was, and accept it to close out this question.

Comment: Actually now that I got access to the object, calling `thisGauge.setCell()` doesn't work because I need to cast it to `google.visualization.Gauge` somehow. Shall I update the question to ask about this issue or create a completely new answer.

Comment: This sounds like a different question all together.  Close out this question and create a new one for the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was due to a typo... The param that was being passed into the `setValue` method does not match the one used to add the items to the dictionary object.